# Spring - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]- NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm a newbie for Spring and I was referring to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm) for my first Spring project. After follow all the instruction, I try to run the program but I'm having this error.

```
May 26, 2015 11:42:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@31221be2: startup date [Tue May 26 11:42:45 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
May 26, 2015 11:42:45 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/ParserContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.ParserContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Any idea where I did the wrong. As I know I was following the tutorial correctly.

CODE

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

      obj.getMessage();
   }
}
```

Beans.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld">
       <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Show your `Beans.xml`. Is that all the code ? Post full stacktrace too.

Comment: @Dishalan2014 have you added all the required jars

Comment: @TSurendra you are correct. I missed one jar. It working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if you have added all the required jars in your classpath.

The class `org.springframework.expression.ParserContext` lies inside `spring-expresssion-YOUR_SPRING_VERSION.jar` Check if you have this jar added on classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. But I found my mistake.

My mistake was, I created **"Beans.xml"** inside `com.tutorialspont` package.

The solution for me was **"Beans.xml"** has to be created **directly under** `src` folder.

Answer (score -1):

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory**(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.javahonk.client.TestWebService.main(TestWebService.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more

**Solution to the above problem:This happens if spring-expression-xxx.Release.jar in not available in your class path. Please add spring-expression-3.2.3.RELEASE or latest version jar in your class path to fix this issue.**